# ApacheDS Object Class Computer

Tags: apache-ds

I have a service that collect data from Active Directory and ApacheDs and I want to know if is possible to have computers data type in ApacheDs

Are there any Apache Ds object classes for Computer like for Active Directory? if yes,can anyone give some screenshots.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.